# Ошибка операции eval

Tags: python, eval

Есть небольшая программа. Цифры и операции вводятся в `entry` при помощи кнопок/клавиш. Расчет осуществлаяется при помощи функции `eval`. Столкнулся со странной проблемой. Если ввести:

> 10 + 5

то `eval` посчитает, а если

> 10 + 05

то начнёт ругаться на 0 в начале числа. Что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идёт о третьем питоне, то проблема не в eval, у вас точно так же и просто в коде ноль в начале числа будет выкидывать ошибку синтаксиса.

На вопрос "что с этим можно сделать" существует несколько ответов:

1. Самый лучший - не использовать eval вообще. Серьёзно, это очень плохая практика. Сделайте нормальный парсер вводимой строки.
2. Если всё-таки первый вариант для вас неприемлем, обрабатывайте строку, прежде чем передать её в eval. В частности, удаляйте ноль в начале числа, но тут ещё много чего полезного можно отфильтровать. Всё таки eval - очень коварная штука, и нужно тщательно проверять, что именно вы подаёте ей на вход. Но лучше всё-таки не используйте eval вообще.
3. Если уж и второй пункт для вас слишком сложен, можете перейти на второй питон, в нём ноль в начале числа не должен создавать ошибки. Но лучше подумайте ещё раз и просто не используйте eval.

Comment: Спасибо, наверное воспользуюсь первым способом.